# Values are not added to a List when using Append

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am having an issue with a class that is used as list object to store information.
My issue relies on the method .Add which is not working and you can see it in the end of the post.

The references to account.email is a different class, and has nothing to do with this.

```
class AccountsLinksStatus
    {
        public string account { get; set; }
        public string link { get; set; }
        public List<int> actions
        {
            get; set;
        }

        public List<int> likes
        {
            get; set;
        }

    }
```

This is the other class where i store the list values

```
namespace Modules.Storage
{
    static class Statistics
    {

        public static List<Modules.Storage.AccountsLinksStatus> accountLinksStatistics;

    }
}
```

And im later then instanciating it like this

```
var act = new List<int> { song };
var defaultValue = new List<int> { 0 };
Modules.accountLinksStatistics.Add(Storage.AccountsLinksStatus { account = Accounts.email, link = link, actions = act, likes = defaultValue });
```

All seems and work ok up till here, but whenever i try to add a value, it wont add anything.

```
var stats = Modules.Storage.Statistics.accountLinksStatistics;
var linkStat = stats.FirstOrDefault(t => t.account == Accounts.email && t.link == link);
linkStat.likes.Append(1);
```

No error exception is trowing so i really dont know what is wrong.

Comment: How do you know it's not adding anything?

Comment: Gongas, for future question please review [MCVE] guidance on adding code to the post. In this particular case most of the code in the question is unrelated - the only thing that matter is `var likes = new List<int>();likes.Append(1);` (which likely would have let you find answer yourself )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Append` method adds an item to the returned collection and not modifying the current collection while `Add` adds it to the current collection.

Change to:

```
linkStat.likes.Add(1);
```